# how do I format my response array in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

***Need to format my array for chart purpose***

```
myArr=[["6709"],["1949"],["87484"],["12760"],["13326"],["3356"],["98000"],["16949"],["29981"],["7879"],["117640"],["30727"],["122071"],["21325"],["210406"],["65824"],["2744807"],["56664"],["382719"],["134578"],["2440528"],["83819"],["1362744"],["450092"],["2461"],["336"],["166446"],["16363"]]
```

***Below Formatted Array***

```
formatArr= [["6709", "1949", "87484", "12760"], ["13326", "3356", "98000", "16949"], ["29981", "7879", "117640", "30727"], ["122071", "21325", "210406", "65824"], ["2744807", "56664", "382719", "134578"] ["2440528", "83819", "1362744", "450092"], ["2461", "336", "166446", "16363"]]
```

Comment: Is there a criteria for the grouping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        myArr = [["6709"],["1949"],["87484"],["12760"],["13326"],["3356"],["98000"],["16949"],["29981"],["7879"],["117640"],["30727"],["122071"],["21325"],["210406"],["65824"],["2744807"],["56664"],["382719"],["134578"],["2440528"],["83819"],["1362744"],["450092"],["2461"],["336"],["166446"],["16363"]]
        formatArr = []

        function makeArray(params) {
            let element = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                element.push(myArr[i][0])
                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                    formatArr.push(element);
                    element = [];
                }
            }
            console.log(formatArr);
        }

        makeArray();
```

This is correct if myArr has 4n element, if not use this

```
function makeArray(params) {
            let element = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                element.push(myArr[i][0])
                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                    formatArr.push(element);
                    element = [];
                }
                if (i == myArr.length - 1 && (i + 1) % 4 != 0) {
                    formatArr.push(element);
                }
            }
            console.log(formatArr);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce it like this for example:

```js
const formatArr: string[][] = myArr.reduce((prev, item, index) => {
    if (index % 4 === 0) {
        // every fourth item creates a new array with the current item:
        prev.push(item);
    } else {
        // every other item pushes to the previously added item:
        prev[prev.length - 1].push(item[0]);
    }
    return prev;
}, [] as string[][]);
```

Comment: am getting this error core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: prev[(prev.length - 1)].push is not a function

Comment: got a fiddle or playground link?

Comment: @ Mr.Manhattan, Fixed.